# can we use single excel object for 2 or more actions in UFT?

Tags: hp-uft

can we use single excel object for 2 or more actions in UFT?
example: I have created excel object in Action1 and can I use same object in another action like Action2.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Please provide an example of what you are trying to do and the specific problem you are running into.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a single object in multiple actions if you declare the object as Public (using a functional library).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to import and export the sheet from inside the execution:

```
Datatable.Export "C:\temp\Script_data.xls"
Datatable.Import "C:\temp\Script_data.xls"
```

This could also be included in a function library as mentioned by [Pankaj Jaju](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318752/can-we-use-single-excel-object-for-2-or-more-actions-in-uft#46318888)